# Getting error when running Jetpack Compose samples

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to run "Owl App" from [Jetpack Compose sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) apps but i got this error:

`This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.2 or newer.`

What's it for?

Comment: Use Android Studio 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue causing due to using of newer version of gradle in the project.

You need to use the [latest canary version](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) of Android Studio.